# Is $_ a package variable in Perl?

Tags: perl

`$_` acts as default parameter for many functions in Perl, is it a normal lexical variable or package package?  I thought it is the former, but I also saw `_` is in symbol table `%main::`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of symbols that are always looked for in package main, instead of in the current package, of which `_` is one.  (This means the entire `*_` glob: `$_`, `%_`, `sub _`, etc.  People doing internationalization periodically trip over that last one.)

Other such symbols are: INC, ENV, SIG, ARGV, STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR, ARGVOUT, and anything that doesn't start with a standard identifier-starting character (including all punctuation and `${^...}` variables).

So the following prints `123` and then `456`:

```
package foo;
$_ = 123;
$foo::_ = 456;
package bar;
print $_;
print $foo::_;
```

but it is a package variable.  (Though there was an experiment to enable `my $_;` to make it lexical for a scope which I believe has been deprecated, and under 5005threads, it might have been a lexical too, I don't recall exactly.)

Comment: See the 2 `package` statements doesn't make any difference for the output?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Is it a question?

Comment: Because it's the `_` *symbol*, `@_` and `%_` also magically always refer to `*main::_`.

Comment: @Schwern: I thought that was implicit in what I said; I tried to make it more explicit.

Comment: @ysth Mostly mentioning it because I never realized it until I saw a co-worker using `%_` "because argument passing is slow". `*headdesk*`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Except for a failed attempt to introduce the ability to do `my $_;`, all punctuation variables<sup>[1]</sup> are package variables.

For example, a common bug is to use the following in a sub:

```
while (<$fh>) { ... }
```

The above code is short for

```
while (defined($_ = <$fh>)) { ... }
```

As you can see, that clobbers `$_`. One should use

```
while (local $_ = <$fh>) { ... }
```

or

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) { ... }
```

What makes the bug worse is that `$_` is frequently aliased to another variable.

```
$ perl -e'
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   sub f {
   my ($qfn) = @_;
      open(my $fh, "<", $qfn) or die $!;
      while (<$fh>) {
         # ...
      }
   }

   my @files = qw( a.txt b.txt );
   for (@files) {
      f($_);
   }

   print("Successfully processed @files.\n");
'
Use of uninitialized value $files[0] in join or string at -e line 18.
Use of uninitialized value $files[1] in join or string at -e line 18.
Successfully processed  .
```

---

There is something interesting about `$_`: It's a "super-global". This means that an unqualified `$_` (or `@_` or `%_`) refers to `$main::_` rather than `$_` in the current package.

```
$ perl -le'
   $_      = $x      = "main";
   $Foo::_ = $Foo::x = "foo";

   package Foo;
   print($_);
   print($Foo::_);
   print($x);
'
main
foo
foo
```

I don't think I've ever had need of that knowledge.

---

1. Punctuation variables consist of a single character other that's not a letter (e.g. `$_`, `$.`, `$]`, `$1`, etc) or they have a name that starts with `^` (e.g. `$^V`, `$^X`, `${^TAINT}`, etc). All my examples are scalars, but the same applies to other variable types.